# RuntimeError: number of dimensions must be sparse_dim (59697) + dense_dim (0), but got 3

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

loading model from model/repro/wikimovie/best_model_doc
epoch 0
0%|                                                                                                                 | 0/1202 [00:02<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\GraftNet\main.py", line 156, in 
train(CFG)
File "D:\GraftNet\main.py", line 55, in train
loss, pred, _ = my_model(batch)
File "C:\Users\TechEnclave Computer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\GraftNet\graftnet.py", line 229, in forward
pagerank_e2d = sparse_bmm(entity_pos_mat._indices(), entity_pos_mat._values(), entity_pos_mat.shape, entity_pos_mat, pagerank_d.unsqueeze(dim=2) / e2d_out_dim)
File "D:\GraftNet\util.py", line 160, in sparse_bmm
X = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(X_I.t(), X_V, torch.Size([B * N, X_shape[1], Y.shape[1]]))
RuntimeError: number of dimensions must be sparse_dim (59697) + dense_dim (0), but got 3

def sparse_bmm(X_I, X_V, X_shape, X, Y):
"""
This function performs batched sparse matrix multiplication (X * Y).
:param X_I: Indices of the sparse matrix in COO format (num_nonzero, 2)
:param X_V: Values of the sparse matrix (num_nonzero,)
:param X_shape: Shape of the sparse matrix (2,)
:param Y: Dense matrix (batch_size * N, K)
:return: Result of sparse matrix multiplication (batch_size * N, K)
"""
B, N, _ = X_shape
X = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(X_I.t(), X_V, torch.Size([B * N, Y.shape[1]]))

```
X = X.to_dense()
X = X.view(B * N, -1)
result = torch.matmul(X, Y)
return result
```

Comment: No one could help you with this mess! Please make your question neat and tidy.

Comment: a quick guide for how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask